# Is it possible for VSCode to execute and debug via SSH, with local source code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am struggling to execute my codes on my Linux VM, with all files inside my local Windows machine.

So, I have my source code at for example:  `D:\myCodes\` and
the files are shared to my Linux VM at `/media/sf_codes`

I linked all my relevant files at `/media/sf_codes/src/` to `/opt/myCodes/src/`. All other files are irrelevant, and only contains about diagrams, SQL files, etc etc that has nothing to do with the Linux VM. So I only link the src folder into the project folder at `/opt/myCodes`.

I have tried to use Remote-SSH extension, but it just to won't load all files. It is either load local files, and disables all SSH shell, or it opens a folder at the Linux VM. Which is not necessary because the files are local. And I need to `su` it under different user to be able to write the files, which complicate things a lot. I was able to do it using Docker or WSL, but their use of HyperV complicate things, and broke many things. So I am back with VirtualBox.

I don't need fancy stuffs like sync or whatever magic they provide, just open SSH shell in terminal, preferably multiple ssh terminals to multiple Linux VMs, and work the files in local folder, and that's it.

I think if they can sync the files, what I need is a basic thing to do, and somehow I missed that. How can I do that in VS Code?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to work with files on your local machine? Why not just use the remote SSH extension [like it is inteded](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) with the source code on the remote side? You can still open these files in your local VS code window as if they were local files (see point 6 [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_connect-to-a-remote-host)).

Comment: @carlfriedrich Because not all files are intended for that remote side. Therefore I said, it would complicate things a lot, by moving my local files to a remote side, because by then, either I have to set up NFS sharing, and I have to share those files to other VMs from that VM. Or I have to work separately, and that would waste time. If I have to work this way, I have to open at least 2-3 VScode apps, one for each VM. Not efficient at all. 
What does make it difficult just by letting me SSH to those machines and let me execute them? It's just a simple bash shell.